# How do I create Flow Chart using Visual Designer in Proteus and take a reading off grove ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: power-electronics

I have this my  schematic
[image]

This is the Visual design
[image]

Comment: ,just emulate the spec https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Ultrasonic_Ranger/ or define your design specs 1st

Comment: That helps alot. Sike!

Comment: yes psychic I am not, but I can read piezo  crystals